# Why my custome CSS stylesheet override my bootstrap web design - symfony 5?

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, bootstrap-4

I want to add a custom CSS file to my web page. However, when I do that, the bootstrap CSS which I added before is overridden and my page seems ugly. So my question is how I can add some custom CSS properties to an HTML tag without losing the design which I've created with bootstrap.

N.B : I'm using Symfony 5 with twig template and bootstrap is not installed I use a cdn.

Here is my code :

showlist.html.twig which extends from base.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h3 style="color: #297323">Liste des annonces publiées :</h3>
    <div class="row pt-4">
        {% for announce in announces  %}
        <div class="col-4">
            <div id="card" class="card mb-5" style="width: 20rem; border-color: #297323;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
                <h5 class="pt-3 px-3">{{ announce.title }}</h5>
                <p class="px-3" style="color: #AAAAAA">Rédigé le {{ announce.createdAt | date("d/m/Y") }}</p>
                <div class="card-body" style="padding-top: 0">
                    <p class="card-text">{{ announce.content | u.truncate(100, ' ... ') }}<span><a href="{{ path('show_one_announcement') }}" style="color: #297323">Lire la suite</a></span></p>
                </div>
            </a></div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}

{% endblock %}
```

base.html.twig :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
              integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl"
              crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% endblock %}

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #297323;">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01" style="padding-left: 1%">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path("home") }}" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Avanza</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #FFFFFF;">
                        Article
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('new_announcement') }}">Création</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ path('show_list_announcement') }}">Consultation</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path("app_register") }}" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Inscription</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path("app_login") }}" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Connexion</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#navbarDropdownMenuLink").click(function(){
                $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
                });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Regards.

YT

Comment: Hi. Can you add the CSS file?

Comment: Yes, but then bootstrap doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I mean here :) We might see the problem, which porbably is because the cascading of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

to solve your issue, please check whether you have attached the custom CSS style sheet below the bootstrap link. If your  tag that holds the customm css style sheet is above the bootstrap style sheet link or the bootstrap's CDN link, it overwrites the properties sometimes. Hope this helps. Thanks